# Batch file parameter with space

Tags: batch-file, parameters

I don't understand this guys.

There is an .exe, which simple writes all parameters to the console.

```
>my.exe "1 2" "3 4"
param[0]=my.exe
param[1]=1 2
param[2]=3 4
```

There is a .bat file

```
set EXE="my.exe"
set A=%~dp1
set B=%~n1.pre.xml

echo 1=%1
echo EXE=%EXE%
echo A=%A%
echo B=%B%

"%EXE%" -p %A% -o %B%
```

Running bat file, output:

```
1="C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\p_27."
EXE="my.exe"
A=C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\
B=p_27.pre.xml

param[0]=my.exe
param[1]=-p
param[2]=C:\Users\xx
param[3]=yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\
param[4]=-o
param[5]=p_27.pre.xml
```

Ok, so it split the path at the space. What I want, not to split the path! Simple, just use quotes:

```
"%EXE%" -p %A% -o %B%
--->
"%EXE%" -p "%A%" -o %B%
```

But output is catastrophic:

```
1="C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\p_27."
EXE="my.exe"
A=C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\
B=p_27.pre.xml

param[0]=my.exe
param[1]=-p
param[2]=C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaa" -o p_27.pre.xml
```

?????? What is going on?
Only closing quote is added to 2nd parameter, and rest of the params are merged to the 2nd??

How can I get this output:

```
param[0]=my.exe
param[1]=-p
param[2]=C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\
param[3]=-o
param[4]=p_27.pre.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the path that ends in a backslash.

When you call the `.exe` file, your arguments are correctly quoted from the batch point of view, but the executable will retrieve the full command line and use its own parser (the standard C parser is usually used) that follow [rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx) different from those in batch files.

This parser will see the `\"` as an escaped quote, so, in your case, it is not the end of the second parameter, but a quote contained in the second parameter that continues until the next quote or the end of the command line.

```
"my.exe" -p "C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\" -o p_27.pre.xml
^0       ^1 ^2                                  ^escaped          ^end of 2nd arg
```

To make it work remove the ending backslash or, if it can not be removed, double it `\\"`. This way, the parser will see an escaped backslash before an ending quote.

Comment: Woaw, never thought that printf style parser is applied on the command line parameters! I just changed `"%EXE%" -p "%A%" -o %B% --> "%EXE%" -p "%A%\" -o %B%`, and that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
set "EXE=my.exe"
set "A=%~dp1"
set "B=%~n1.pre.xml"

echo 1=%1
echo EXE=%EXE%
echo A=%A%
echo B=%B%

"%EXE%" -p "%A%" -o "%B%"
```

> 1="C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\p_27."
>   
>   EXE=my.exe
>   
>   A=C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\
>   
>   B=p_27.pre.xml
>   
>   
>   "my.exe" -p "C:\Users\xx yy\AppData\Roaming\aaaa\" -o "p_27.pre.xml"

Comment: Same result as my quotes try: Only closing quote is added to 2nd parameter, and rest of the params are merged to the 2nd.